# Is there an RSpec formatter which can play an audio file when specs pass/fail?

Tags: rspec, formatter

I came in touch with the funny [Nyan Cat Formatter](https://github.com/mattsears/nyan-cat-formatter) which is able to play music while the specs are running.

Because our test suite is growing and growing I often do something else while it is running, e.g. browser on the internet. It would be great though to have an audio signal when the specs have finished (or when one fails), so I know when to return back to work.

Is there a formatter like this? If not, I'll try to create one myself by taking a look at how the Nyan Cat Formatter works.

Thanks for help
Josh

Answer (score 4):

You can do something simple just on the shell like:

```
rake spec && say 'pass!'
```

`say` is a Mac thing but I'm sure similar are available for other platforms.

Comment: That's a nice hint! It's not really what I'm looking for but will definitely prove useful in certain situations. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work for me. Simply typing `say "hello"` works, but when chaining it like `rspec && "say hello"` nothing happens.

Comment: I'm going to assume the wrongly placed quoted as just a typo in your comment, so it seems the RSpec command isn't exiting successfully. Are you tests definitely passing? If you want to make a sound regardless of success or failure, just replace `&&` with `;`

Answer (score 2):

I just made this Gist which makes it dead simple to do, and you don't need anything other than rspec (and sox, which you can install through `apt-get`):

[Play a sound after an Rspec suite](https://gist.github.com/yjukaku/8138580)

```
  config.after(:suite) do
    examples = RSpec.world.filtered_examples.values.flatten
    if examples.none?(&:exception)
      file = "spec/pass.wav" 
    else
      file = "spec/fail.wav"     
    end

    fork{exec "play -q -V0 #{file}"}

  end
```

This goes in your `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Snoop dog sings Gin & Juice when things are chillin now.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [autotest](http://rubygems.org/gems/autotest) to let it run your tests it can be [configured to use a plugin to play sounds](https://github.com/unimatrixZxero/.files/blob/master/.autotest) when the test run starts or when it ends.